# Incorrect radio button getting selected for ng-repeat radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of radio buttons using ng-repeat.
When I initially load the page and select on the last radio button, the button on it's side gets selected.
This only happens for the first time, i.e. if I click on the last button a second time, it is selected correctly.

```
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="{{rbCollection.name}}" data-ng-click="open(name)" data-ng-model="Ctrl.selection">
```

Comment: radio buttons ng-model must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685522/ng-click-function-evaluating-on-second-click-or-unclick).

> The problem is that ng-click fires before the ng-model code that updates the scope. If you change it to use ng-change, that will fix it. You also need to add ng-change to your text box to update the scope as the user types.

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.