# Incorrect Radio button selected on first time in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my HTML code for radio buttons

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input name="isOwner" ng-model="art.isOwner" ng-required="!art.isOwner" ng-value="1" type="radio" id="radio11">
        <label for="radio11">Yes</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input name="isOwner" ng-model="art.isOwner" ng-required="!art.isOwner" ng-value="1" type="radio" id="radio21">
        <label for="radio21">No</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

When i click on `yes` button it will select `no` radio button but its only happens in first time

I've found a question similar to my issue

[Incorrect radio button getting selected for ng-repeat radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612352/incorrect-radio-button-getting-selected-for-ng-repeat-radio-buttons)

But its hard to understand the solution for the problem

Comment: Can you update a plunker for it?

Comment: they have the same values on purpose?

Comment: wrap your labels around the inputs else they don't know what ID to associate.

Comment: yes its for some purpose

Comment: @Elisha thanks for point out the issue when the values are different it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the labels around your inputs like so:

```
<label for="radio21">
  <input name="isOwner" ng-model="art.isOwner" ng-required="!art.isOwner" ng-value="1" type="radio" id="radio21"> No
</label>
```